# Sufficient conditions for constant solutions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth **negative** function that satisfies
$$-f(x)u(x) + B(x) = \Delta u(x),~\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^N,$$
where $B(x)$ is a smooth positive function and $f$ is a smooth function with at least one zero. In particular, one can decompose $\mathbb{R}^N = \Omega\cup \Omega'$, where $f\Big|_{\Omega} > 0$. One easily sees that $\Delta u(x) > 0$ for all $x\in \Omega,$ i.e, $u$ is subharmonic on $\Omega$. In my particular, it also holds that $x'\in \partial\Omega$,
$\Delta u(x') > 0.$

Is there any sufficient condition on $f$ in order to conclude that $u$ is constant on a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^N?$ What if we instead of $\mathbb{R}^N$ one considers a smooth closed manifold?

Comment: How do you conclude the positivity of the Laplacian? I feel like you are missing some hypotheses on $f$. Besides, it is not clear for me if the equation contains $f(u)$ or $f(x)u(x)$...

Comment: @Sharik, I am sorry, I will edit, consider seeing again, please

Comment: @Sharik I have edited.